# Selling my primary GoDaddy domain. Recommendations on how not to not break things?

Tags: email, domain-registration, godaddy

My father and I are selling our family business and with it, our domain name.  We are not selling the website or the hosting itself.

The domain and is registered AND hosted on GoDaddy, with one subdomain and a number of other domains hosted under that account.

We are only selling/tranferring the primary domain.

In addition, we have a secondary domain name which is currently redirected to the primary.

What I'd like to do is:

- Unlock `Mopedepot.com` so it is ready to transfer.  I have done this.
- Get the transfer key ready.  I believe I have this too
- Get anything else ready that might be needed. (Unknown)
- Transfer the domain  without breaking any of the existing sub sites I have
- Set up `50cccycle.com` as my primary domain
- For a time, have email send to `mopedepot.com` sent to both domains until all of the incoming email stuff has been updated.

Any suggestions or gotchas I should be aware of?

Comment: Looks like you got everything under control. You could always set the name servers or a records for them before you transfer that way they don't need to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure that the ID protection/Private registration has been turned off for the domain name before you initiate the transfer.

2) The EPP code or the transfer auth code can be obtained from your domain control panel or Godaddy.

3) You can get the primary domain name changed to 50cccycle.com from your hosting provider. If you have access to the hosting panel, you can make the changes yourself or else you will have to contact your hosting provider.

4) Are you using Linux/Windows/Java hosting?

Comment: Thanks @Nilabh -- In this case we were just transferring the domain name, not the full hosting.  Everything went through without a hitch.